# GraphQL Cannot query field \"childImageSharp\" despite the feild being available on graphiql

Tags: graphql, gatsby

Im getting this error  "Cannot query field "childImageSharp" on type "StrapiHomesGalleryImageFormatsMedium" for any childimagesharp variant i pick, even though they are selectable on the left hand-side menu. I can't figure out why its not queryable when everything else works fine. Galleryimage is an array of images.

[image]

the app code -

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql, Link } from "gatsby"
import Image from "gatsby-image"
import ImageGallery from 'react-image-gallery';

const ComponentName = ({ data }) => {
  const {id, galleryImage} = data.home
  console.log('data is', data)
  
  const images = [];

return (
    <Layout>
    <section className="template">
    <ImageGallery items={images} />;
    </section>
    </Layout>
    
)
}

export const query = graphql`
  query GetSingleHome($slug: String) {
    home: strapiHomes(slug: { eq: $slug }) {
    galleryImage {
      formats {
        large {
          childImageSharp {
            fluid {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
            }
            id
          }
        }
        small {
          childImageSharp {
            fluid {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
            }
            id
          }
        }
      }
    }
    MainImage {
      childImageSharp {
        fluid {
          ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
        }
      }
    }
    }
  }
`
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue with Strapi and childImageSharp when you allow multiple images in the Strapi field. Go to the content type builder in Strapi, and try to change the media from Multiple to Single image.

Unfortunately if you want to use GatsbyImage, it has to be a single type from Strapi at the moment.